# keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_F wont work

Tags: android, keyevent, keycode

I have a problem with my android algorithm. I want some certain thing happends when the user presses f. or any word, i've tried most of them and the space, the only codition that's working is:

```
if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER && event.getAction() == 0)
```

Here's the part that has a problem:

```
else if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_F && v.getId() == R.id.EditText1)
        {
            .. certain algorithm ..
        }
```

Thanks for ur trouble :)

Comment: There shouldn't be any problem with "keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_F"  Are you sure "v.getId() == R.id.EditText1" is working?

Comment: Can you debug which condition fails? the keyCode or the v.getId() it possible that you are importing the R from the android package instead of your application package?

Comment: Do some logging, and before you enter that 2nd else if() statement, log `v.getId()` and `R.id.EditText1`. What is `v`? I forget what `R.id.EditText1` will return, but if that's a String, use `.compareTo(str)`, not `==`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_F) {
        do something...
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

or you will try

```
   @Override
   public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
             do something...
       return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
   }
```